# Generating Pythagorean Quadruples with one fixed value?

Tags: geometry, computer-science, complexity-theory, computational-geometry, time-complexity

If I wanted to generate unique (ignoring negatives) Pythagorean quadruples (of the form a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = d^2) with a fixed d (in this case 2^15 - 1), is there a better than O(n^3) way of doing this?

Right now I'm pretty much brute forcing it with:

```
int r = (1 << 15) - 1;

for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
 for(int j = i; j < r; j++)
  for(int k = j; k < r; k++)
   if( i * i + j * j + k * k == r * r )
    //add to list
```

Which is O(n^3), is there a faster way?  I found some snippits that could generate the quadruples, but they all said they might miss some.  I saw the equations for them, and I thought there might be some linear system of equations way?

Comment: You can eliminate half the search space by observing that exactly 1 or 3 of a, b and c must be odd if d is odd, or exactly 0 or 2 if d is even. This trick may extend to moduli of other small primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameterization at [previously-mentioned Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple) says

> All Pythagorean quadruples ... can be generated from two positive integers a, odd, and b, even ...
>   Let p be any factor of a^2 + b^2, such that p^2 < a^2 + b^2. Then c = (a^2 + b^2 − p^2) / 2 and d = (a^2 + b2^ + p^2) / 2. ... A similar method exists for a,b both even ...

which appears to be a straightforward O(n^2) method to generate all Pythagorean quads, but without an obvious way to capitalize on `d` being fixed.

Here is another O(n^2) method that requires no mathematical insight, just some basic data structures ability:

```
   for(k=0; k<r; ++k)
     insert r^2 - k^2 into BST [*]

   for(i=0; i<r; ++i)
     for(j=i; j<r; ++j)
       if i^2 + j^2 is in BST report i,j,k [**]
```

[*] Any high speed dictionary data structure can used; binary search trees are not obligatory.  However, [AA trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_tree) are fast, and easy to code.

[**] Compute `k` from k^2 = r^2 - i^2 - j^2.

Answer (score 1):

It would still be O(n^3), but you could speed it up a bit by not searching numbers that are too big:

```
...
for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
  for(int j = i; j < sqrt(r^2 - i^2); j++)
     for(int k = j; k < sqrt(r^2 - i^2 - j^2); k++)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with parameterizations, [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple) mentions 2 of them.